# Show standard SharePoint ribbon in custom list form

Tags: 2013, ribbon

I have created a custom list form, inside the Layout folder and attached to the custom list,
for new item and edit item..
However I want to show standard ribbon on my custom page.
Any help to achieve this ?

Answer (score 1):

The answer can be found here: http://mysharepointt.blogspot.com/2012/03/sharepoint-ribbon-on-layout-pages.html

Basically it requires custom markup on your layouts page.